# How to determine if a variable exists in another Python file

Tags: python, file

I have two python files. From python file #1, I want to check to see if there is a certain global variable defined in python file #2.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
try:
    from file import varName
except ImportError:
    print 'var not found'
```

Alternatively you could do this (if you already imported the file):

```
import file
# ...
try:
    v = file.varName
except AttributeError:
    print 'var not found'
```

This will work only if the var is global. If you are after scoped variables, you'll need to use introspection.

Comment: Is it OK to put in import statement in the middle of the code? By OK I mean not bad convention.

Comment: Sure, it's totally acceptable to defer module loading to a later stage.

Comment: You could also just `import file` at the beginning, and later on check for `file.varName`, exactly the same way.

Comment: Alrite your comment is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I do have a problem in the script. For some reason, it goes into the try statement, passes, then goes to the except statement?

Comment: If there's only one line in the `try` block that is impossible. You are debugging wrong.

Comment: Yea I figured it out. For some reason when I do v = file.varName, its still going into the except statement even when the variable exists

Update: using getattr(file, varName) works

Answer (score 8):

You can directly test whether the `file2` module (which is a module object) has an attribute with the right name:

```
import file2
if hasattr(file2, 'varName'):
    # varName is defined in file2…
```

This may be more direct and legible than the `try… except…` approach (depending on how you want to use it).

Comment: Could we also get its value?

Comment: @Yuval Adam's `try` solution would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

With the `getattr()` built-in function you also can specify a default value like:

```
import file2

myVar = getattr(file2, attribute, False)
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

Comment: This does not generally answer the original question: what if the variable exists and is false?

Comment: Then the answer would be False anyway so still correct although i see what your saying